# Python Split after converting float to String results in unexpected Scientific Notation

Tags: python, string, function, split

I'm struggling here lol

I'm working on a function that take a long number, convert it to a string, and then format it to standard US format (i.e. 42509348509 to 42,509,348,509). It's working great... unless I've got a decimal and a number that is larger than the function likes (number varies) then I start getting scientific notation responses.

Here's the function as it is right now:

```
def format_number(num):
num = str(num)
decimal = ''
if '.' in num:
    parts = num.split('.')
    num = parts[0]
    decimal = parts[1]
digits = len(num)
if digits < 4:
    return num
current_set = len(num) % 3
format_num = ''
for number in num:
    if not format_num and current_set >= 1:
        format_num = format_num + number
        current_set -= 1
        if current_set == 0:
            format_num = format_num + ','
            current_set = 3
    elif not format_num and current_set == 0:
        format_num = format_num + number
        current_set = 2
    elif 0 < current_set <= 3:
        format_num = format_num + number
        current_set -= 1
    else:
        format_num = format_num + ',' + number
        current_set = 2
if decimal:
    format_num = format_num + "." + decimal

return format_num
```

If there's a more elegant way of doing this, I'm happy to hear it, too, but it's functional ... mostly. I'm assuming this is some sort of memory limitation? To give you an example of what I get:

base number: 9999999999999.32
returns: 9,999,999,999,999.32 (expected)

base number: 999999999999999.32
returns: 999,999,999,999,999.4 (incorrect decimal)

base number: 9999999999999999.32
returns: 1e,+16 (qua?)

base number: 1111111111111111.32
returns: 1,111,111,111,111,111.4 (wrong decimal, but took all the 1s where I got scientific notation with 9s)

The fact that lower numbers are returning slightly better results leads me to believe it's got to be a memory limitation or something to that effect. I can't find anything on here that seems to fit this particular situation. I'm fairly new to Python, so I apologize if this should be a no brainer.

Thanks all!
Aaron

Comment: This is Python's internal conversion. You will see the same behaviour if you just print that number as well. One easy elegant way is `f'{num:,}'`, which also outputs the same.

Comment: Is there no way around that?

Comment: so what is your question exactly? does [that](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/) answer it?

Comment: No, I understand the basic data types. what I'm not clear on his how to get Python to *not* display my string as scientific notation. I want the longer string.

Comment: You have to deal with strings only. For ex: `format_number('999999999999999.32'))`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that @Austin? Line two of my function ensures that num is set to "str"... Am I missing something?